# discord.py main thread being blocked

Tags: python, discord.py

I have a very simple bot that makes a request to `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` every 0.5 second (this is a practice project, I know it's not recommended) but, Upon running the bot, It starts, but due to the high amount of requests, It won't execute `sayHi()` due to the thread being blocked.

What I want: Is a way to execute the requests inside another thread, If possible?

```
@bot.command()
async def sayHi(ctx, arg):
    print("Hi")

async def make_request():
   r = requests.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1")
   print(r)

@tasks.loop(seconds=0.5)
async def scan_loop():
    await make_request()

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is running")
    scan_loop.start()

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Of course, you can use `multiprocessing` or `threading` to run a request in another thread but there is a second way: using asyncronous [`aiohhtp`](https://docs.aiohttp.org/en/stable/) instead of blocking `requests` library.

So, your `make_request` function will be something like this with `aiohttp`:

```py
import aiohttp


async def make_request():
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        async with session.get("https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1") as response:
            print(await response.json())
```

Comment: `httpx` is another asynchronous HTTP client.

Comment: @AKX Yes, I think it is also usable.